# Why does JOptionPane interfere with System.out.write()?

Tags: java

If the line containing `JOptionPane` is commented-out, the code simply prints out whatever is typed in the console until you hit enter. But having the said line in your code will not only fail to show the expected message dialog, the previous line containing `System.out.write(c)` also seems to fail. Why?

```
public static void ioTest04() {
    try {
        int c;
        while ((c = System.in.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.write(c);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "'c' value is: " + c);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works as expected on my system.   Can you show us `java -version` and `uname -a`?

Comment: Can you try doing `System.out.flush();` after doing your write?

Comment: adding `System.out.flush()` after `System.out.write()` does print the first character of my first input. After that it works just as id did before this edit.

Comment: What means "fail to show the expected message dialog"? Die dialog doesn't appear _after_ typing a key? If that's the case you should know that dialog buttons react on *releasing* a key, so don't try return or space key...

Comment: I mean the dialog never appears. I continue typing text and pressing enter but there's no MessageDialog and no output from the `System.out.write()`.